# SKEffectNode shouldRasterize broken in iOS 9.2?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, skeffectnode

I remember since the origins of SpriteKit that it has never supported a `SKCropNode` inside another `SKCropNode`. For that reason I decided to use a `SKEffectNode` along with the `shouldRasterize` property in the child node, which seems to work fine.... until now.

Since iOS 9.2 the sprites inside the `SKEffectNode` using this property now are either not showing or showing a plain white texture. As `SKCropNode` inside `SKCropNode` still doesn't work I'm out of options.

Does anyone know a workaround for this? Or should I just file a radar to Apple?

Answer (score 0):

We found another "hackish" workaround for this problem. Basically, instead of using a `SKEffectNode` to rasterize it you can use `- (nullable SKTexture *)textureFromNode:(SKNode *)node` from `SKView`.

So, previously it was sort of:

```
SKEffectNode *rasterizedSprite = [SKEffectNode node];
SKSpriteNode *mask = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"maskImage"];
SKCropNode *cropNode = [SKCropNode node];
[cropNode setMaskNode: mask];
[cropNode addChild: spriteToMask];

[rasterizedSprite addChild:cropNode];
rasterizedSprite.shouldRasterize = YES;

[self addChild:rasterizedSprite];
```

Now it's like:

```
SKSpriteNode *mask = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"maskSprite"];

SKCropNode *cropNode = [SKCropNode node];
[cropNode setMaskNode: mask];
[cropNode addChild: spriteToMask];

SKView *view = [[SKView alloc]init];

SKSpriteNode *rasterizedSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[view textureFromNode:cropNode]];

[self addChild:rasterizedSprite];
```

This workaround might give problems with iOS8 and below...